# Bluetooth not really "turning on" on a Sony Vaio VPCEG

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, vaio

On a Sony Vaio VPCEG, bluetooth is not working properly:

- The gnome-shell bluetooth indicator (at the main bar) shows the
  bluetooth is on, but when I try to switch visibility on it simply
  doesn't turn on.
- When I open the bluetooth configuration dialog, the on/off indicator
  shows me the bluetooth is off. And when I try to turn it on it simply
  does not turn on.

The following is outputted by `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64be Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e027 Foxconn / Hon Hai
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 4971:ce22 SimpleTech
```

======

Update: Output from `rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

What should I do to really activate the bluetooth?

Comment: Finally found a response. How can I answer my own question?

Comment: can you tell me how you have solved your problem? I'm facing the same problem....

Answer (score 2):

This is not a fix, but it can solve the problem temporarily.

If you use dual-boot between Ubuntu and Windows, boot to Windows first. Then *turn on* the hardware switch for *wireless*.

After that, reboot into Ubuntu. Bluetooth will work now.

Comment: not working here

Comment: What about wi-fi ? It works fine..?

Comment: yep, wi-fi works fine and it turns on and off normally.

Comment: Can you post output of `rfkill list` ?

Comment: just added `rfkill list` output to the question's body :]

Comment: Can't find solution yet..:) Can u enable it through `sudo hciconfig hci0 up` ? Look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11972551

Comment: I receive a timeout error, just like the other people in the forum you pointed. I'm afraid there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have vaio VPCEG35EN model.
I enabled wifi by blacklisting acer_wmi module , but bluetooth is not working even though its always on in windows, and no soft or hard blocking in linux.
Morever I doubt bluetooth hardware recognized in linux may not be correct because its an atheros bluetooth not foxconn.
anyway here is  output from lsusb and rfkill

```
parijat@UbuntuBook:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:64be Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0489:e027 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
parijat@UbuntuBook:~$ rfkill list
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Vaio vpceg too, and I was searching around for answers and discovered that the problem occurs when you wake up the device. As dixonck says, if you reboot into windows, turn Bluetooth off and on and restart without shutting off the laptop, and then enter Ubuntu, you will see that Bluetooth works. However, if you switch off Bluetooth or shut down the laptop, it will not work.

Isn't a Ubuntu issue, is a Linux issue, i have tested it in several distros and it happens in them all.

I think Sony makes a hardblock that completely stops the Bluetooth devices.